# How do I display PDF documents stored in Azure blobs in an iframe?

Tags: azure, iframe, azure-blob-storage

I have a bunch of PDF documents in an Azure blob store.
Given the URL of a particular PDF, I need to be able to embed it in a web page like so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>iFrame PDF Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>A PDF Document Embedded in a Web Page</h1>
<iframe src="https://azure.server/my-container/folder/my-document.pdf" width="100%" height="800px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

This HTML works for a web hosted PDF file, but when I use a blob URL I see the following error message.

```
ResourceNotFoundThe specified resource does not exist. RequestId:********-****-****-****-************ Time:2023-02-27T17:44:33.2977066Z
```

I get the same error if I put the blob URL directly into the browser.
The blob referenced by the URL exists and its content type as specified in the Azure UI is `application/pdf`.

This question pops up online, and the consistent answer I've been able to find is that there's [something wrong with the permissions](https://www.spguides.com/the-specified-resource-does-not-exist-azure-blob-storage/), which makes sense.
As far as I can tell, though, I have permissions set up correctly.

On the container page, it says "Authentication method: Access key".
If I click "Change access level" I see this dialog box.

[image: Access level dialog box]

Which I interpret to mean that the current access level is Public, which should be what I need.

I am able to generate an SAS token for my container, which may be what I need, but I don't know how to use it.

How do I see this up?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the screenshot you shared, the current access level for your blob container is private. I would recommend changing it to `blob` or `public`.

If you want to use a SAS URL, you can do that as well. Please create a SAS URL with `read` permission and use that URL instead of blob URL in your code. However, please note that once the SAS URL expires, you will start to see the same result as you are seeing now.

Lastly, please make sure that content-type property of the blob is set correctly (it should be `application/pdf` for PDF files). If you don't do that, then the blob will be downloaded instead of displaying it in an iframe.

Comment: +1, Specifying `content-type` as **`application/pdf`** is the key, file uploaded without specified content-type will be `application/octet-stream`.